# Compute the integral $\int_{\gamma} F dt.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate the integral of $\vec{F}=(y(8x+1),18y^2)$ over the curve
>   $\gamma$ along the ellipse $4x^2+9x^2=4,$ counterclockwise from the
>   point $(-1,0)$ to $(-\sqrt{2}/2,-\sqrt{2}/3).$

I have that $P(x,y)=y(8x+1)$ and $Q(x,y)=18y^2.$ The formula I need to use is

$$I=\int_\gamma Pdx+Qdy.$$

The ellipse can be written as $(2x)^2+(3x)^2=4,$ so parameterizing by $(x,y)=\left(\frac{\cos{t}}{2},\frac{\sin{t}}{3}\right),$ so

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    dx & = & -\frac{\sin{t}}{2} \ dt \\
    dy & = &  \frac{\cos{t}}{3} \ dt\\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Also, drawing a figure...

[image]

...reveals that $t\in[\pi, \pi + \arctan{2/3}],$ thus my integral becomes

$$I=\int_\pi^{\pi+\arctan{2/3}}\frac{\sin{t}}{3}\left(8\frac{\cos{t}}{2}+1\right)\cdot \left(-\frac{\sin{t}}{2}\right) + 18\left(\frac{\sin{t}}{3}\right)^2\cdot\frac{\cos{t}}{3} dt = \\ = -\frac{1}{6}\int_\pi^{\pi+\arctan{2/3}}\sin^2{t}=\frac{1}{26}-\frac{\arctan{2/3}}{12}.$$

This is not correct.

Comment: When you parametrized the ellipse you forgot 4 on the right side. The correct parametrization is $x=\cos t,y=\frac 2 3 \sin t$.

Comment: Then the answer becomes $$\frac{2}{13}-\frac{\arctan{2/3}}{3},$$ still not correct.

Comment: what is the correct answer??

Comment: I don't know. I can only find it out by entering it in a special website. If it's wrong, it says it and if it's correct it says it.

Comment: try using integral calculator online using correct parameters(as suggested by Kavi).

Comment: I did just that.

Comment: Noone who can shed light on this problem?

Comment: @Parseval Unless there are other typos in your question statement, I can confirm that $\displaystyle \frac{2}{13}-\frac{\arctan{2/3}}{3}$ is correct. It could be that this "special website" made an error in documenting the correct answer. Another possibility is that things can go wrong in how you key in your answer.